# Objective-C/Cocoa Chunked File Upload

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file-upload

I'm relatively new to Objective-C/Cocoa development. I'm currently working on a Mac application where i need to upload a file to a web server using HTTP PUT requests. I'd like to break up the file to several chunks and stream it to the server rather than reading the whole file into the memory and uploading it in one go.

I have come across several third party libraries (ie: ASIHTTPRequest, AFNetworking) which can support this functionality out of the box. However, i'd like to go ahead without using third parties for the time being due to several constraints of the project.

Any assistance in this regard is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just uploading a file, without a Multipart MIME wrapper, then I believe you can setup an input stream directly from NSMutableURLRequest.  Getting an NSInputStream for a file on-disk is easy, using +[NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:].  I've not done this exactly myself, but I think it will work.

If you do end up needing to do a Multipart MIME wrapper, then I'd recommend using a library.  It is a total pain to get right, and has some quirks to deal with depending on what OS version you are running on.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I may be wrong here, but from what i can see in the official documentation for NSMutableURLRequest (setHTTPBodyStream method), we need to set the complete content of the request body before sending it to the server. This would essentially mean we need to read the full contents of the file into memory isn't it ?

Comment: From apple documentation: "The inputStream should be unopened and the receiver will take over as the stream’s delegate." I'm also stuck with this issue, I don't have the entire stream content in memory...